# Fetching replace text with image, do not working HTML Prob

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This is my code:

```
echo "<div class=\"panel-body\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-color:#ddd\">";
echo "<div class=\"vidMR\">";

echo"<div><strong>" . $lang['vldMaker'] . "</strong></div>";
echo"<div>";
$maker = "SELECT vidMaker FROM videoinformation WHERE id=".$row['id'];
if ($result1 = mysqli_query($con, $maker)) {
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {
        $values = explode(',',$row2[0]);
        foreach($values as $v1)
        if (!empty($v1)) {
           printf ("<img src=\"addVid/maker/%s.jpg\" class=\"makerImg img-circle\"  alt=\"%s.jpg\">", $v1, $v1);
        }
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result1);
}
else{
    echo $lang['vldErrorMaRo'];
}
echo"</div>";



echo"<div><strong>" . $lang['vldRoles'] . "</strong></div>";
echo"<div>";
$role = "SELECT vidRoles FROM videoinformation WHERE id=".$row['id'];
if ($result2 = mysqli_query($con, $role)) {
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
        $values = explode(',',$row3[0]);
        foreach($values as $v2)
        if (!empty($v2)) {
           printf ("<img src=\"addVid/roles/%s.jpg\" class=\"roleImg img-circle\" alt=\"%s.jpg\">", $v2, $v2);
        }
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result2);
}
else{
    echo $lang['vldErrorMaRo'];
}
echo "</div>";




echo"</div></div>";
```

Problem is that this code working ONLY in chrome and opera, BUT in IE and Mozilla pictures are not displayed...

I tried different ways...like add full path for images and so on... BUT any way it's would not like to work in IE and Mozilla.

This is out put HTML...

```
<body>
    <div class="vidMR">
        <div>
            <strong>Maker:</strong>
        </div>

        <div><img alt="Name1.jpg" class="makerImg img-circle" src=
        "addVid/maker/Name1.jpg"><img alt="Name2.jpg" class=
        "makerImg img-circle" src="addVid/maker/Name2.jpg"></div>

        <div>
            <strong>Roles:</strong>
        </div>

        <div><img alt="Name1.jpg" class="roleImg img-circle" src=
        "addVid/roles/Name1.jpg"><img alt="Name2.jpg" class=
        "roleImg img-circle" src="addVid/roles/Name2.jpg"><img alt="Name3.jpg"
        class="roleImg img-circle" src="addVid/roles/Name3.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it works in Chrome and Opera then the problem is likely not PHP nor mysqli. It's probably with your HTML. You could update your post with the generated HTML output or link to a pastebin and maybe we can figure it out

Comment: @EricPing edit, have a look

Comment: Your HTML looks valid. What about your CSS?

Comment: Sorted... problem was with bad images....(who knows).. so I replace the image (just download a new one) and everything working fine...